# getter & setter in Swift VS getter & setter in Java

Tags: swift, getter-setter, swift5

I'm really confused about the purpose of getter and setter methods in Swift as someone coming from Java world

so in Swift there is something called computed property which lets you create a dynamic variable and you can provide setters and getters for a specific property just like this

```
var property: Int {
    get {
         return anotherProperty - 4
    }
    set {
        print("property now has a new value which is \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

the setter gets executed **after** the property gets assigned with a new value ex:

```
property = 100
```

what i don't understand is that setters in general are called **when we want to set a  new value** not **after** the value is set, that is their purpose and that is why it is called setter(it sets the property with a new value).

am i getting it all wrong? or if i am right then what is the purpose of setters in Swift and why are they useful at all if it's not for setting the value of a property?

Comment: Read [this chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) from the Swift Programming Language book about properties

Comment: Maybe you are confused with `set` and `didSet`.